# When is the "=>" syntax in relation to defining a function in javascript and what is its significance?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm just learning `node.js` so Im not sure if this a `node.js` question or a `javascript` question but Im not sure what this syntax is/is saying. I don't believe it's being to compare  less than or greater than values as I've seen it used like so in `node.js` apps

```
router.use('/intro', (req, res) => {

});
```

What is the "`=>`" saying / what is it's significance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a javascript question, it is a new way to write functions...

This is simply es6 arrow function syntax.

ES5

```
var a = array.map(function(s){ return s.length });
```

ES6

```
var b = array.map( s => s.length );
```

Your code in ES5:

```
router.use('/intro', function(req, res) {

});
```

Note:
Differences with Lexical this

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value (a new object in case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the context object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be annoying with an object-oriented style of programming.

See these docs for more info

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: awesome this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: edited answer, check it out

Comment: this is not a new way of writing functions, it is an arrow function, which isn not the same as a normal function

Comment: @JordanHendrix your answer is misleading, arrow function is a new feature introduced for various reasons (the main ones are: 1. bind `this` 2. concise syntax ). Which means, arrow function are not here to substitute normal functions. You cannot use arrow function with generators, and in some other scenarious